# Checking for a simple form being posted in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a simple login form, at the top of this page i check for the form being submitted to i can process the login if it's been submitted.

```
if (!empty($_POST))   {
echo "form submitted";
}
else {
?>
<form style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <div class="content">
                    <h4 class="title">Login Access</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="foot">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </form>
<?php } ?>
```

I've tested with a var_dump($_POST);, but it doesn't display any post variables when submitted. I'm using XAMPP in my production enviroment, so i'm wondering if thats the issue?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 3):

The form doesn't have `method="post"`, so you are making a GET request and `$_POST` will be empty.

Even if that wasn't the case, none of your form controls have `name` attributes, so they cannot be successful (so won't generate any data to put in the form).

Answer (score 3):

By default forms submit their values via `GET`. To change this you need to set the `method` attribute of the `<form>` tag to `POST`

```
<form method="post" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           HERE
```

As Quentin pointed out already, you are also missing the `name` attribute in your form elements. So even your `$_GET` would be empty if you checked it.